# how to name dataset/variable using concatenation

Tags: macros, concatenation, sas

I have a problem with SAS 9.2.

I'm writing a simple macro which creates dataset and name it according to the variables submitted and some other words/letters/signs, for example

```
%macro example(var1,var2);

data &var1 || '_word_' || &var2;
    a=1;    
run;

%mend;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

- Pipes are only for strings within SAS, not within SAS macro. So don't use them here.
- SAS Macro does not interpret quotes as indicating a string, it will just read them, so leave out the quotes.
- If you want to concatenate elements in macro, you just need to write them appended to each other.
- To make clear where the macro variable name ends, append a dot.

This should work:

```
%macro example(var1,var2);
    data &var1._word_&var2.;
        a=1;    
    run;
%mend;
```